# problem in uv map

Tags: uv

please . can any one test my character----when I make UV it give me an error ---and there are some vertics arround layout

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1f5tTVljeaiRxlt2bLrYm9am4jaqZEni3?usp=sharing
[image]

Comment: What's the error that it's giving.  It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and add that link in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is UV of eyes which don't have seam to unwrap.
You can select eyes and go to *UV > Unwrap > Sphere Projection* without creating seam.

[image: After Unwarp both eyes with Sphere Projection method.]
*After Unwrapping both eyes with Sphere Projection method.*

To diagnose your problem you can use [UV Sync Selection](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/uv/selecting.html#:%7E:text=Turning%20on%20the%20Sync%20Selection,components%20in%20the%20UV%20editor.) and select some weird vertices in UVmap and <kbd>Ctr</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to select all link vertices. And you will see problem UV on viewport.

[image]
*Turn on UV Sync Selection to see all UVmap without selection on viewport.*

Comment: THANK YOU FOR REPLY-----BUT PLEASE I CANT UNDERSTAND THE PROBLEM----WHY THESE VERTICS ARROUND CHARACTER APPEARS

Comment: AFTER I SELECT THESE WEIRED VERTICS---WHAT CAN I DO AFTER THAT?

Comment: After selection, unwarp with Sphere Projection(https://jpst.it/2QhIN). Please don't edit people post with your question or shouting with all caps and consider reading Expect Behavior : https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/behavior

Comment: thank you all ---solved